# How to convert a string date value to actual date data-type in snowflake

Tags: sql, string, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have a date which is in the format 15-NOV-2019

I am trying to convert this date format in snowflake in actual date data-type i.e. 15/11/2019

I am using this function in looker for conversion `try_to_date (15-NOV-2019 , 'DD-MMM-YYYY')` in snowflake but its giving me null as output

if i will summaries my query -My input date is **15-NOV-2019** and I am trying to get this format **15/11/2019** after conversion but using this function `try_to_date (15-NOV-2019 , 'DD-MMM-YYYY')` it is giving NULL as output

how I can achieve this conversion in snowflake please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Just change DD-MMM-YYYY to DD-MON-YYYY:

```
select try_to_date ('15-NOV-2019' , 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```